# VSTS Authenticating with vssClientCredentials

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I am currently trying to connect to a VSTS project using the code below, I have previously connected successfully after entering credentials into the dialog box shown.

```
if (!IsConnected)
{
    sourceControl = release.SourceControl;
    connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(sourceControl), new VssClientCredentials());
    workItemTrackingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
}
```

The dialog box is no longer shown and an exception is thrown:

> TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client
>   authentication required.

I am unaware of any changes that could have caused this to break, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can delete the cached credential from registry: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio` (delete **VssApp** key)

You also can specify the credential storage:

```
var c = new VssClientCredentials();
c.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage(storageKind: "VssApp2", storageNamespace: "VisualStudio");
connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(sourceControl), c);
```

Comment: Would also like to add to anyone else having a problem with this, we were also having problems due to this call not being in its own separate thread, in one part of our application this would throw the same error message

Comment: @Chris:  That registry key was causing some confusing in our team as well.   It's presence meant some users did not have to re-authenticate at all.  The MSFT guys explained that the key is created by VS2015 and the ExtendClient libraries (I assume the NuGet libraries and maybe TF.exe as well but I'm not sure on the last point).  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48111383/vs-2017-credentials-cache-registry-key-created-for-some-users-and-not-others-w