# VS 2017 credentials cache registry key created for some users and not others - why?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, azure-devops

This is a follow on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48098682/tfs-online-programmatic-access-is-working-for-some-users-without-credentials-w).

There is a registry key used to cache VS 2017 credentials:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp
```

This key has been created for some of our developers but not others.

I would like to know why?

Is there some special way to log in that creates this key?  We obviously all have to log in to use VS 2017.

Why do some of us have this key and others do not?

NOTE: special thanks to @starian who helped me with the previous question.

Comment: Isn't it created for users that ticked "Remeber Me" checkbox during signing in?

Comment: @cloudikka:  I thought so at first but I am pretty sure I checked the "Remember Me" checkbox and I have not got the key...  I had to shelve this investigation for a bit so I can't be 100% but I will double check again tomorrow.  Thank you for looking at my question and posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VS2015 and the TFS ExtendedClient Library stores and uses the credential in that registry path but VS2017 does not. I suspect that some of your developers signed in with VS2015 before and then upgraded to VS2017 or they signed in with the ExtendClient Library before.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  This does actually make sense.  The devs who have the key did in fact have VS2015 before.  The ones that don't (including me) skipped 2015.  The service accounts that are working appear to be working because another developer logged them in using TF.exe.  I assume this would have the same effect as logging in programatically using the extended client libraries (NuGet package or Team Explorer installation folder)?

Comment: @J M Yes, when you login with the extended client library, it do the same as VS2015. It will use the token stored in that registry. And if there is no key existed there, it will prompt a sign in dialog ang then generate a new key base on the credential you entered in the sign in dialog.

Comment: hi Eddie would you know where VS2017 stores the credentials and how can we access those programmatically?